# Json data return together in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I have json column with this data:

```
{
  "address":"testing address, phone number, country, state, name of the person etc.",
  "post_method":"tiki",
  "post_price":"15000",
  "weight":"2"
}
```

now when I try to return this data in my view like:

```
@foreach($order->shipment_data as $shipment) //shipment_data is the name of json column which holds this data
 {{$shipment}}
@endforeach
```

It returns all data under `address`, `post_method`, `post_price` and `weight` together like it's a paragraph.

I am not able to get each part separately like:

```
{{$shipment['post_price']}}
```

it returns:

> Illegal string offset 'post_price' (View:

**Any idea?**

## Update

results of `{{dd($order->shipment_data)}}`

```
"{"address":"fake address here...","post_method":"tiki","post_price":"15000","weight":"2"} ◀"
```

Comment: Add index 0 first before post_price

Comment: @aldrin27 `Illegal string offset`

Comment: Do you need to `json_decode()` the data?

Comment: As @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin suggest decode first your json.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I don't think so because before i used to store my data with `json_encode` and it adds \ before each part then i removed that encode code so now it's just saving an array actually `{` i don't think i need decode as long as i don't encode them

Comment: Based on this.... `It returns all data under address, post_method, post_price and weight together like it's a paragraph.` So it may mean that they are string, so you can `json_decode($shipment, true)` in order to use the data as an array.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin sorry but it confused me `$shipment` is my singular part of the loop how do i add json_decode into it?!

Comment: Please can you show the code for your controller method?

Comment: @RossWilson this is all happens in my blade my controller just return `$orders`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already casted it to an array, in your case, `$order->shipment_data` is just an array. You could access the individual column as follows:

```
$order->shipment_data['post_price']
```

There's no need for the `foreach()`.

Comment: it says `Trying to get property 'post_price' of non-object`

Comment: You do need to use `json_decode()`. See the updated answer.

Comment: when i do your way `@foreach(json_decode($order->shipment_data) as $shipment)` it says `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: could you `dd($order->shipment_data)` and add it to your question?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert json into array. You can do that with json_decode function. Also if you use new version of Laravel, you can cast from json to array in model, by adding

```
protected $casts = [
    'shipment_data' => 'array',
];
```

and this should work.

Comment: You need just 


 {{$order->shipment_data->post_price}}


without loop